# AngularJS and ExpressJS http error handling

Tags: angularjs, express, error-handling

I'm curious what is the correct approach at http error handling within a MEAN setup. Lets say I have an express route setup that looks like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    fetchSomeData(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            // Okay some error occurred
            return res.send(500, err); 
        } else {
            // All fine
            res.json(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And an AngularJS http fetch that looks like this:

```
$http.get('/api/things/')
    .then(
         function (response) {
             // Data received
         },
         function (httpError) {
             // Some http error occurred
         });
```

If I send a 500 error when I wasn't able to fetch some data then It will log in the console developer console of the webpage `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` which might not "look" so good for the end user.

I'm thinking, if I instead in the express route `if (err)` clause just do a `res.json({ error: "Handle this error"});`

Then I will be able to look for in AngularJS `$http` if the response contains an error and then show this error for the user and the user does not have to see the nasty 500 error.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: So you actually try to bypass the browser javascript error log ? I don't really see the point till 500 are always unexpected. If you can do a specific handling of an error you should just use some other HTTP Response Code and handle them specifically in Angular.

Comment: Basically I'm wondering what is the purpose of sending any other response code (than 200) to AngularJS? Within the 200 respponse code if there is an error, I can set the property `error` in the response and then parse the error in the $http success method? Why would I want to output any error (like 500) to the browser javascript log? I don't think the end user cares about that anyway as long as the user is informed that some error has occurred.

Comment: Actually the user don't really care about the browser javascript logs (he don't even know how to display it). The only purpose is to handle some things like "Bad requests" "Gateway Timeout" etc... to have a better handling of the response. ("Should i stop my function ? Should i just try again after a timeout ? etc...") In any way we use a JSON object in the body request to have a better message. But all of this may be a matter of taste. You actually can get the status in the error function like this ('error(function(data, status, headers, config)')

Answer (score 0):

You are more or less correct in your approach. To handle errors with expressJs, add an exception handler at the end of  your route handlers as,

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if(!err) return next()
  console.log(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send({status:"error", message: err.message})
})
```

And ensure, you don't catch exceptions inside your route handlers, otherwise, the `err` object will be `undefined`.

Now, on the client side, you can check `if (data['status'] == "error")`, then show a warning to the user with `data['message]`.